# An analytic function in a compact region has finitely many zeros

Tags: complex-analysis, compactness, analytic-functions

I’m trying to solve the following problem, but I can’t. I need your help.

Recall (Sec. 11) that a point $z$ is an accumulation point of a set $S$ if each deleted neighborhood of $z$ contains at least one point of $S$. One form of the Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem can be stated as follows: an inﬁnite set of points lying in a closed bounded region $R$ has at least one accumulation point in $R$. Use that theorem and Theorem 2 in Sec. 75 to show that if a function $f$ is analytic in the region $R$ consisting of all points inside and on a simple closed contour $C$, except possibly for poles inside $C$, and if all the zeros of $f$ in $R$ are interior to $C$ and are of ﬁnite order, then those zeros must be ﬁnite in number.

My attempt is as follows

Suppose there are infinitely many zeros.

Then by Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, there is a point $z\in R$ such that every deleted neighborhood of $z$ contains at least one zero.

Then there are two cases.

1. $f$ is analytic at $z$
2. $z$ is a pole

I solved Case 1. Since $f$ is continuous at $z$, $f(z)=0$.
Then by theorem 2 in Sec. 75, which states that if an analytic function $f$ is not zero function near a zero then the zero is isolated, $z$ has a deleted neighborhood that does not contain any zeros. This contradicts that $z$ is an accumulation point of zeros.

How can I deal with Case 2?

Comment: If $z$ is a pole, for some integer $M > 0$, $g(w)=f(w)(w-z)^M$ is analytic near $z$, and has zeroes accumulating around $z$.

Comment: Umm... Sorry I don’t understand. Could you explain more? The function g is not zero at z ?

Comment: It is, if $M$ is large enough.

Comment: So g is analytic and nonzero at z. But z is an accumulation point of zeros. So g(z) must be zero. So this contradicts g is nonzero at z?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ has a pole at $z$ then $|f (\zeta)| \to \infty$ as $ \zeta \to z$. Hence there is a deleted neighborhood in which $f$ has no zeros.

Comment: Thanks! But could you explain more why there is such deleted neighborhood?

Comment: There exists $\delta >0$ such that $|f(\zeta)| >1$ whenever $0<|\zeta -z| <\delta$. So $f(\zeta) \neq 0$ for such $\zeta$.

Comment: Oh! Right! Thanks! But I’m little bit worried. I learned f goes infinity as ζ goes z in section 77. But this exercise is from section 76.

Answer (score 3):

If $f$ has infinitely many zeros in a compact region $K$ then, since $K$ is compact, there is a sequence $(z_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of those zeros which converges to some $z_0\in K$. By the continuity of $f$, $f(z_0)=0$ then. But it follows from this that the set of zeros of $f$ has an accumulation point (which is $z_0$) and therefore, by the identity theorem, $f$ would be the null function.

Comment: Thanks! But I don’t understand why f is continuous at z0. If z0 is a pole, f is not analytic.

Comment: I am assuming that $K$ is a subset of the domain of $f$. Besides, a sequence of zeros cannot converge to a pole because, if $f$ has a pole at $z_0$, then $\lim_{z\to z_0}\bigl\lvert f(z)\bigr\rvert=\infty$.

Comment: Umm I think I still don’t get why a sequnce of zeros cannot converge to a pole. I wanted to show this when I’m trying to this exercise, but I couldn’t. Could you explain it more?

Comment: If $z_0$ is a pole of $f$, then $\lim_{z\to z_0}\bigl\lvert f(z)\bigr\rvert=\infty$. Therefore, there is a $\varepsilon>0$ such that $\lvert z-z_0\rvert<\varepsilon\implies\bigl\lvert f(z)\bigr\rvert>1$. *In particular*, $\lvert z-z_0\rvert<\varepsilon\implies f(z_0)\neq0$. In other words, $f$ has no zeros in the open disk centered at $z_0$ with radius $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Do you assume f is continuous at z0?

Comment: No. *As I wrote*, I assume that $f$ has a pole at $z_0$.

Comment: I learned that in the definition of limit, |z-z0| < ε should be deleted neighborhood unless it is continuous.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, nice answer